# Django models error: ValueError: Field 'cat' expected a number but got '-'

Tags: django, django-models

i just add 2 models to my class
and i got this error:

```
ValueError: Field 'cat' expected a number but got '-'.
```

my code:

```
# Create your models here.
class News(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(default=',', max_length=50)
    name = models.CharField(default=',', max_length=50)
    short_txt = models.TextField()
    body_txt = models.TextField()
    date = models.CharField(default=',', max_length=12)
    writer = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    catname = models.CharField(max_length=20, default='-')
    catid = models.IntegerField(max_length=10, default=0)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

I had a cat model, but I removed it before...

Thank you for your time<3

Comment: No field called cat, Put full code please

Comment: hey, this is the problem, i havent cat model...:)

Comment: You don't have a `cat` model, you have a `News` model. `catname` and `catid` are fields in that model. How did you delete your previous model?

Comment: You said you have 2 models, Where's the second one

Comment: i deleted it form code and then makemigrations,,, so i havent it, and i havent 2 class i check all my models but i didn't found ***cat***,,, idk what i have to do @AhmedI.Elsayed

Comment: Delete the `migration` folders and make migrations again

Comment: i delete it from code and then make migrations and then migrate,,, @JohnFilleau

Comment: Log into your database and manually delete the table called `mysite_News`.